# How would I record time in voice channel and display it in my !!userinfo command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to store voice hours in the channel

here is what I have so far and I am stuck I don't know what to put after I have tried to look it up no solution

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel 
let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

function start() {
    startTime = new date()
}

}else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
function end() {
endTime = new date()
var timeDif = endTime - startTime;

}
}

});
```

I want it to record voice hours in a .json file under the guild name and username of the person and I am stuck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your `if` statement (as well as the `else` clause) you create a function but you never call said function. There are 2 ways to fix it, you can see them listed below.

Option 1: calling the functions after creating them

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel 
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

  if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

    function start() {
      startTime = new date()
    }

    // Call the function after creating it
    start();

  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined) {

    function end() {
      endTime = new date();
      var timeDif = endTime - startTime;
    }

    // Call the function after creating it
    end();

  }
});
```

Option 2: removing the function declaration and just executing the code (in my opinion the better/cleaner option)

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel 
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

  if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    startTime = new date()
  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined) {
    endTime = new date();
    var timeDif = endTime - startTime;
  }
});
```

Note that the code might not work as you had in mind. Say personA joins a voice channel then `startTime` will be set. If then personB joins a voice channel, the `startTime` variable will be overwritten by the new `new Date()` value. If you want to store the start time for each specific user, you would need to store it somewhere related to the user. Say an Array of Objects with the properties `user` and `startTime`

Comment: how would I store it?

Comment: Either a database or a local `JSON` file would suffice. You can also story it in a local variable (array of  objects) but this might get really big if a lot of people join a voicechannel

Comment: I guess a ` Discord Collection` would be a efficent way to store it. Otherwise you may also be able to do something like `newMember.user.voiceTime = ....`